# jQuery How to Continue Javascript to New Line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

This is lingering question I have and while it may seem like a noob - that's ok as I am one.

How do I continue a new line in jQuery selectors ? I understand that javascript new lines are simply

`(\) single backslash`

Such as

```
var someString = 'abc\
defghi';
alert(someString);
```

Yet using jQuery - this doesn't work when I am listing long selectors ? i.e.

```
$('#id, .class, .class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5, \
   .class6, .class7').click(function() {
      //some stuff
});
```

Can anyone shed some light how to resolve this ?

Comment: why don't you simply give all those items a single common class?

Comment: @Spudley - doesn't really matter as this is just an example ;) i could have 10 different `ids` I am targetting in one common js file across the entire site ? doesn't really matter whethers it's classes or not - picture as `id's` if it helps.

Comment: That's a new line within a string... not within the context of the code as in your second example.  You don't need to do this... it's all on one line and the "wrapping" is only a function of your text editor's preferences.

Comment: or using event delegation attach the event to the parent of all these classes and hear for the event target

Comment: @Tom Perhaps you have a space or some other invisible characters after the backslash?

Comment: nope :) seems you can't actually do it! you have to use @alienwebguy's answer below.

Comment: @Tom Nope. You can do it! I have tested your code and it works! Look: http://jsfiddle.net/QrtHE/

Comment: Somebody please explain the "why?".  As in, what's the need for this when text editors can auto-wrap long lines for display purposes?

Comment: @Sparky672 Sure, if you want you can write all your program code in one line, because the text editor auto-wraps the code for display purposes :)

Comment: @Karolis:  I never said anything about putting **all** the program code in one line.  But in the case of the OP's question, the editor will auto-wrap that **one** line just like the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Sparky672 Editor wraps the code at its own position, also the next line begins at offset 0 and usually this is not what we want. When you do this manually then you are under full control of code representation.

Comment: computer languages typically don't allow line breaks in the middle of a string. js does. but I should think it should with a \ unless the EBNF specifically says it does not belong in a string. js has some oddities if it is not escaped. it expects one-liners, etc and perens and more conditional don't necessarily mean the statement will "continue". it might get cut off as is usually the case with long if statements.

Answer (score 20):

```
$('#id, .class, .class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5, ' + 
  '.class6, .class7').click(function() {
      //some stuff
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6QjK/

Comment: I wonder - will this affect performance in any way ? :) [just wondering :)]

Comment: It's negligible but concatenation is definitely slower for obvious reasons :) http://jsperf.com/to-concatinate-or-not

Comment: It's worth noting that there won't be a performance loss if the code is minified.

Answer (score 5):

What's inbetween the `$()` is simply a string.  With that said, how would you split a string into two pieces?

```
$('big selection text' +
  'more selection' + 
  'more selection still')
```

Alternatively, you could add to your collection after your initial selection:

```
$('big selection text')
    .add('more selection')
    .add('more selection still')
```

Answer (score 4):

Today another option is using template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
$(`#id, 
   .class, 
   .class1, 
   .class2, 
   .class3, 
   .class4, 
   .class5,
   .class6, 
   .class7`).click(function() {
  //some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` ***is*** JavaScript. Don't be fooled into thinking that there's a difference. Is your code working with everything on a single line?

I'd guess that your selector is not actually selecting any elements (DOM elements probably don't exist when the selector is called).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, strings cannot span multiple lines, so to encode a multiline string you would do the following:

```js
var s = "This is a\n" +
        "multiline\n" +
        "string.\n";
```

Note that the newline characters (`\n`) are only required if you really want newlines in the string.  Your example would look like this:

```js
$('#id, .class, .class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5, ' +
  '.class6, .class7').click(function() {
    //some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just close the string and use the `+` operator to add the strings.

```
$('#id, .class, .class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5,' +
   '.class6, .class7').click(function() {
      //some stuff
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason for this not working for you is that when you feed the string over multiple lines like this, it obviously includes a new line character. Possibly jQuery doesn't like this newline being in its selector string.

My advice would be to simplify things by giving each of the elements you want this to apply to a single shared class, which would negate the need to have excessively long selector strings like this.

But if you can't do that, then you can resolve the problem by breaking the string into separate sections and using `+` to concatenate them, rather than continuing the string over a line line.